# How get corresponding element in sub list based on input element from the same list python

Tags: python-3.x, list, sublist

I've list like this.

```
list=[[['name1','name2'],[n1,n2]], [['name3','name4'],[n3,n4]]]
```

I want to get **n1** if input is **name1**

similarly if input if **name3** then output should be **n3**

```
Note: name1-Type str
      n1-   Type int
```

Is there is any way to do this?..Pls suggest me solution/Solution steps that i can follow to solve this issue..

Comment: Are the sub-lists guaranteed to be 2 lists with 2 elements each?

Comment: yes, there will be exactly 2 elements in each sub-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see building an intermediate lookup dict from `my_list`, then looking up as you like:

```py
my_list=[
  [['name1','name2'],['n1','n2']], 
  [['name3','name4'],['n3','n4']]
]

lookup = {}

for double_tuple in my_list:
    lhs, rhs = double_tuple
    zipped = zip(lhs, rhs)  # ['name1','name2'],['n1','n2'] → ['name1', 'n1'],['name2','n2']
    lookup.update(dict(zipped))

print(lookup['name1'])  # → 'n1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily solved with a list comprehension:

1. unpack the elements in the list
2. filter for k1 == input
3. get first result, if exists

```
input_ = "name1"
list_ = [[['name1','name2'],[n1,n2]], [['name3','name4'],[n3,n4]]]
candidates = [v1 
              for (k1, _), (v1, _) in list_
              if k1 == input_]
if len(candidates) == 0:
    print("No such key: " + input_)
else:
    print("Value is " + candidates[0])
```

Note: I used trailing underscores in the names to avoid overwriting builtin functions (`list` and `input`). Overwriting builtin functions is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` combined with `next`:

```py
def get_item_from_key(input_list, key):
    """Return item corresponding to a specific key"""
    try:
        return next(filter(lambda x: x[0][0] == key, input_list))[1][0]
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

So, if the input list is `a = [[['name1', 'name2'], [0, 1]], [['name3', 'name4'], [2, 3]]]`, you can ask for any key you are interested into:

```py
get_item_from_key(a, 'name1')  # this will return 0
get_item_from_key(a, 'name3')  # this will return 2
get_item_from_key(a, 'name2')  # this will return None
get_item_from_key(a, 'name5')  # this will return None
```